# How to achieve a huge number of for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I would like to write a program to get every sum from a list.
For example:

L = [['7'], ['3', '8'], ['8', '1', '0']]

I would like to get:

8 + 3 + 7

8 + 8 + 7

1 + 3 + 7

1 + 8 + 7

0 + 3 + 7

0 + 8 + 7

So, I wrote my program in this way:

```
 for x1 in L[-1]:
     for x2 in L[-2]:
         for x3 in L[-3]:
             print (int(x1) + int(x2) + int(x3))
```

However, there may be a huge number lists. In this way, I have to write a huge number of for loop. Is there any other way that I can use to write my program?

`itertools.product` works well for this question, but is there any way to do not import anything to solve this question?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `itertools`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Because this is a practice and we are not allowed to import extra packages.

Comment: If `itertools.product` can not be used, `reduce` is a good choice. `reduce(lambda x, y: [a+b for a in x for b in y], L)`. Output: `['738', '731', '730', '788', '781', '780']`

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate, since `itertools` can not be used.

Comment: @citaret thank you very much. But `reduce` also need an extra import. If it is possible to achieve this without import?

Comment: Have you tried that? `reduce` is an [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), and you can use it without import.

Comment: @citaret:  OP is using Python 3 where `reduce` is not a built-in function.

Comment: If `L` always has three sublists you can `[int(a)+int(b)+int(c) for a in L[0] for b in L[1] for c in L[2]]`

Comment: So, if you use python3, you can implement `reduce` yourself, as in: `xs = L[0]; for ys in L[1:]: xs = [a+b for a in xs for b in ys]` .

Comment: @StevenRumbalski sorry, there a plenty of sublists

Comment: @Mangosteen:  If you can't import `itertools.product` then reimplement it using the example code [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)